# Importing Neopixel

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, adafruit-circuitpython, neopixel, adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel

I am working on a project that requires adafruit circuitpython neopixel. So I ran

pip3 install neopixel

It said I need to create a virtual environment so I did and ran the command in it and it said successful. I went to my python script to import neopixel

import neopixel
Error: No module named ‘neopixel’

So I went back to the terminal to run

pip3 install neopixel

pip install neopixel

pip install adafruit_circuitpython_neopixel

pip install rpi_ws281x

All these commands ran successfully and I ran them in my virtual environment. Then I went back to my script to import neopixel and the same no module found error popped up again.

I then ran
pip show rpi_ws281x
and then
pip show neopixel

Both said they were downloaded.
I deleted and reinstalled to try again and the same error occurred after running in my script
I looked on the internet for awhile to find solutions and it seemed people as similar issues but no solutions.